# Selenium Connection Refused on Apache Web Server

Tags: python, django, apache, selenium

I have an app that runs selenium on user requested URLs. The app works completely fine on the django dev server on an aws ec2 instance. Deploying the same project--on the same server--on an apache prod web server creates the following error (if I allow django debug to remain on):

```
Exception Type: TimeoutException at /
Exception Value: Message: connection refused
```

I am using the geckodriver with firefox v. 71 and the newest geckodriver.
I point to the absolute path of the geckdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=path_to_driver, service_log_path=path_to_log)
...
```

Currently I am not using pyvirtualdisplay whereas everything worked fine on the same server in dev. When I did try to use pyvirtualdisplay I had the same results.

I think it may be a permissions issue with apache and the webdriver, but I'm not sure.
I did grant apache executable permissions to the geckodriver:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu www-data 7008696 Jan  8 03:02 geckodriver
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Deploying via nginx and gunicorn works fine. I am not marking as solved since this is only a work around for future users. Here is a nice reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-and-configure-a-new-django-project

Comment: What about iis?